# I want the color box to change dimensions as soon as soon as I input values but it is not doing so

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener

The color is changing but the dimensions just wont change and I don't understand what's wrong with the code...

```js
const heightBox = document.querySelector('.box-height');
const widthBox = document.querySelector('.box-width')
const input = document.querySelector('.color-input');
const colorBox = document.querySelector('.color-box');

input.addEventListener("change", function() {
  colorBox.style.backgroundColor = input.value;
  colorBox.style.height = heightBox.value + 'px';
  colorBox.style.width = widthBox.value + 'px';
});
```

```css
.color-box {
  background-color: limegreen;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="color-box"></div>
<input class="color-input" placeholder="Type a color here!" /> <br>
<input class="box-height" placeholder="Type Height Here!" /> <br>
<input placeholder="Tpye Width here!" class="box-width" />
```

Comment: What are you inputting for the dimensions?

Comment: Your code works for me, if I first input heigth and width (sth like "3px" or "5em", not just a number) and then type something in the color input and unfocus it. If you want the dimensions to change when you change their value, you must add EventListeners to the inputs for height and width and change the dimensions inside them

Comment: @Apollo79  
i dont know how its working for u... 
by adding event listener ... u mean i should create a seperate addEventListener or something else?
this is whats happening
https://imgur.com/gallery/PS4kcuP

Comment: Since it'll be used multiple times, I'd turn the event listener into a standalone function, then add to each: `function updateColorBox() {colorBox.style.backgroundColor = input.value; colorBox.style.height = heightBox.value; colorBox.style.width = widthBox.value;} document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(i) {i.addEventListener("change", updateColorBox);});`

Comment: @Apollo79 It worked .... i just added + 'px' at the end of heightBox.value .... so basically it is receiving the value in px.... 
However, when i was writing 13 px in the box .. it didnt work.. was it because the prototype.value only extracts the integers out of the input.

Comment: You do not listen for the changing of the values on the width and height. So in order for those to change, you would need to set a new color.

Comment: @Anshul no, if you wrote exactly "13 px", it didn't work, because there should be no space between "13" and "px". input.valie gets the complete value of the input

Comment: @Anshul the imgur gallery doesn't work for me, what I meant was that the dimensions don't change if I input sth in the heightBox or widthBox inputs. The dimensions only change if I typed something in the color input. You should consider adding event listeners to the width and height inputs and change height and width in them and not in the color input change listener.